# Is it possible to get an error when accidentally assigned wrong type in python?

Tags: python, types, casting, variable-assignment

For example I have next code:

```
name = str('John Doe')
```

Let's imagine after I assign to `name = 1`, but code still valid.
Is it possible to get an error in this case in Python or within some special tool?

Comment: Calling `str` here is redundant; `'John Doe'` is *already* a `str` value. Python is dynamically typed: it is *never* an error to make any name refer to a value with a different type than its current value. (Put another way: *values*, not the names that refer to them, have types.) That said, you can provide type annotations that tools like `mypy` can use to do static type analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is dynamically typed, so you can assign pretty much anything to anything. This would work:

```
name = 1
name = "Bill"
```

You can add in type checking with mypy

Comment: is there no way to throw an error even if I use "name: int = 1"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are trying to raise an error, or just wondering if an error might arise if you change the value.

**Raise an error**

you could check the type using `isinstance(obj, class)` and `raise TypeError(msg)`.

**Is it possible to get an error?**

Not directly, but you could as a consequence get an error if you use string operations/methods on an integer.

Example:

```
>>> name = "john doe"
>>> name = 1
>>> name.split(" ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```